# ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size

Tags: python, scipy, classification, wav, mfcc

**i am classifying two classes of audio samples(.wav files).
Below is the sample code where error arises,**

```
> for curr_class in classes:
>     dirname = os.path.join(data_dir_train, curr_class)
>     for fname in os.listdir(dirname):
>         with open(os.path.join(dirname, fname), 'r') as f:
>             rate,sig = scipy.io.wavfile.read(f)
              mfcc_feat = mfcc(sig, rate)
              train_data.append(mfcc_feat[1:9, :])
```

While running the code i encounter the below error:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.py:267: WavFileWarning: Chunk (non-data) not understood, skipping it.
  WavFileWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/NIKHIL/PycharmProjects/major1/try1.py", line 44, in <module>
    rate,sig = scipy.io.wavfile.read(f)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.py", line 258, in read
    is_big_endian, mmap)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.py", line 129, in _read_data_chunk
    data = numpy.fromstring(fid.read(size), dtype=dtype)
ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the format of the wav file.  Scipy does not support 24 bit files.   Which version of scipy are you using? (Check with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`.)  Scipy version 0.16 and later should give a more informative error message when it tries to read a 24 bit file.

Comment: my wav files are 48khz and 16bit and i am using 0.18.1 scipy version.

Comment: hi @WarrenWeckesser,  I am trying to classify two different languages audio clips.Please suggest me any techniques to classify(plzz mention about feature extraction). Is there any audio preprocessing tools to consider only the required part of the audio clip(splitting or trim the audio files) to extract featres(to save time)

Comment: *"my wav files are 48khz and 16bit and i am using 0.18.1 scipy version."* OK, so the problem is not that the samples are 24 bit.   Now I just noticed that you use `open(os.path.join(dirname, fname), 'r')`.  That opens the file in "text" mode, but for a wav file, you must use binary mode.  Change that call to `open(os.path.join(dirname, fname), 'rb')`.

Comment: thanks @WarrenWeckesser it worked for me ::)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser your answer saved me a lot of time. Seriously. Thanks for being on this site.